# Maintain the changes after hiding and re-open form c# visual studio Windows Forms App

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a program that has 5 forms.
Form 1 is a "menu" with 4 buttons , each open a new form. But I want to be able to do some changes on `datagridviews` that are on these forms (2 to 5), click on buttons that are on these forms , go back to the menu while hiding the one that I opened, and if I click the button to come back, I want to still have the changes that I made on the `datagridview`.

My problem is that I have default values in the `datagridview`, and if I add rows, delete rows or change some cells, and click button to go to "menu"

```
this.Hide();
Form1 sistema = new Form1 ();
sistema.ShowDialog();
```

and come back

```
this.Hide();
Form2 sistema = new Form2 ();
sistema.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

,  the `datagridview` changes to it´s default values.
So I wanted to, for example, hide `form2` without closing and come back later, without loading the form2 again so that the `datagridview` stays the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is too much missing and it is unclear what the question is. Can you provide a code example of what is not working as expected? Also, I suggest you peruse the SO [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section as it shows how SO works. The [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are creating new forms all the time instead of showing the hidden forms again.

You could store a reference to the forms in the class `Program` like this:

```
static class Program
{
    public static Form1 Form1 { get; private set; } // Add these two lines
    public static Form2 Form2 { get; private set; }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form1 = new Form1(); // Add this two lines
        Form2 = new Form2();
        Application.Run(Form1); // <= Change this line
    }
}
```

Now  your two code snippets become something like this

```
this.Hide();
Program.Form1.ShowDialog();
```

and come back

```
this.Hide();
Program.Form2.ShowDialog();
this.Close(); // After having done this, you can't show it again!
```

I.E., you access the existing form objects instead of creating a new one and show them again with either `.Show()` or `.ShowDialog()`.

---

Another solution is to pass a form in the constructor of the other form

```
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Form1(Form2 form2)
    {
        _form2 = form2;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The you can access it via the private field

```
_form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I used your first method but it had a error on the line          `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false)` ,it said "System.InvalidOperationException: 
'SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.' ". Do you know why?

Comment: It’s because the form properties are static, so they run before Main - just create them in there instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Application.OpenForms Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0) to get the instance of the hidden form.

```
// button in form1: hide the form1 
private void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

---

```
// button in form2: reopen the form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
    form1.Show();
}
```